# Can a program executed with PyInstaller work with local files?

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping, pyinstaller

I used pyinstaller to turn a python program that scrapes urls from an excel doc into an executable file. One of the user inputs is the name of the excel doc. Do pyinstaller executables work with local files? My excel doc and executable are in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they should, as long as your code is not hard-coded, and finds the current path of the file, you should be able to find the file anywhere in the current directory that you set.

Comment: I have my excel file and executable file in the dame directory, however it says that there is no such file or directory. The directory that my exe wants to run in leads to itself.... the exe file is called 'test_gen_pac'. And it is automatically running in the directory '/Users/jakegehri/Desktop/Python_Code/tilde/genpac/deliverable/test_gen_pac'. My excel file is in the file 'deliverable'. Thank you!

Comment: please include the line that loads the file.

Comment: `filename = input("What is the filename? ")
sheet_name = input("What is the sheet name? (ex. Sheet1, Sheet2, etc.) ")
column_in_number = int(input("Which is the company type column in number format? (ex. A = 1, B = 2, etc.) "))
pro_column_number = int(input("What is the first 'Pros' column in number format? "))
url_header = input("What is the header for the column with the url's? ")
df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=sheet_name)`

Comment: these are the inputs that the program takes.